# Exclude Multiple Values from results in XML data

Tags: php, xml, feed

I have an XML feed which I am retrieving data from.

I currently have the code written to find an ID and then skip it and show all other results.

XML Code is below

```
 <Agents>
   <Agent>
      <id></id>
      <description></description>
      <name></name>
   </Agent>
 </Agents>
```

Current PHP code below

```
  <?php
     $html = "";
     $url = "xml feed";
     $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
     $idToFind = 1922;
     for ($i = 0; $i < 300; $i++) {
         $id = $xml->Agent[$i]->id;
         if ($id == $idToFind)
             continue;
           {

         $id = $xml->Agent[$i]->id;
         $name = $xml->Agent[$i]->name;

         $html .= "<h2>$name</h2><h3>$id</h3>";}

     echo $html;
```

?>

So at the moment it finds ID 1922 and excludes it, but I want to exclude multiple IDS i.e. 1922, 1845, 2110 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about an array with the id's to exclude?
Then just check if the id is "inArray" with each iteration.

```
<?php
     $html = "";
     $url = "xml feed";
     $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
     $idsToFind = array(1922, 1845, 1234, 8347 ... ...);
     for ($i = 0; $i < 300; $i++) {
         $id = $xml->Agent[$i]->id;
         if (in_array($id, $idsToFind))
             continue;
           {

         $id = $xml->Agent[$i]->id;
         $name = $xml->Agent[$i]->name;

         $html .= "<h2>$name</h2><h3>$id</h3>";}

     echo $html;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be using xpath query to modify xml result.

```
$str = "<Agents>
   <Agent>
      <id>1</id>
      <description>a</description>
      <name>a</name>
   </Agent>
   <Agent>
      <id>2</id>
      <description>b</description>
      <name>b</name>
   </Agent>
   <Agent>
      <id>3</id>
      <description>c</description>
      <name>c</name>
   </Agent>
   <Agent>
      <id>4</id>
      <description>d</description>
      <name>d</name>
   </Agent>
 </Agents>";

$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
$result = $xml->xpath('//Agent[not(id = 1 or id = 3)]');
echo "<pre>"; 
print_r($result);
```